# TypeError: Object marks has no method 'forEach' in nodejs mongojs

Tags: mongojs

I am writing a nodejs application that uses express and mongojs.The express works fine but when i add mongojs i get an error.

```
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var database = "collegeApp";
var collections = "marks";
var db = mongojs(database,collections);
```

the error shown looks like its a mongojs library error.

```
TypeError: Object marks has no method 'forEach'
        at new Database (/home/justACoder/Desktop/projects/collegeApp/project/node_modules/mongojs/lib/database.js:14:13)
```

Also i have another project that is not running concurrently but when i run that project no error occurs.It runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the error.Its the fact that the collections passed was not an array and thats why the forEach function wasn't present.